# how to write this perforce client spec?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I want to map a directory to different local folders (such as `AA/adir` and `BB/adir`) at the same time.  Here's the spec below, but it doesn't work well.

Is there anything wrong?

```
//depot/adir/... //cws/build/AA/adir/...
//depot/adir/... //cws/build/BB/adir/...
```

Comment: Can you explain your reasons for wanting to do this, there may be a better way?

Answer (score 7):

In perforce, there is a strong requirement that there be a one-to-one relationship between the depot and a workspace. From [the doc](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/o.views.html):

*All views construct a one-to-one mapping between files in the depot and the files in the client workspace, branch, or label. If more than one mapping line refers to the same file(s), the earlier mappings are overridden. Mappings beginning with a hyphen (-) specifically exclude any files that match that mapping. In client views, mappings beginning with a plus sign (+) overlay previous mappings. (Overlay mappings do not apply to branch or label views.)*

so a mapping like:

```
//depot/adir/... //cws/build/AA/adir/...
//depot/adir/... //cws/build/BB/adir/...
```

only activates the second line (which wins the conflict).

To do what you want, you need to use two different clients (workspaces) each having one line of your example.

You could look at overlay mappings, and maybe work around your problem:

*An overlay mapping is used to map files from more than one depot directory into the same place in the workspace.*

```
//depot/dir1/... //cws/build/...
+//depot/dir2/... //cws/build/...
```

Comment: thanks ,i tried before i posted this question ,it did work also.

Comment: just like you said   An overlay mapping is used to map files from more than one depot directory into the same place in the workspace...but my requirement is map one depot directory into many folders. that's totally different ..:)

Comment: sorry typo ... acturally, i tried this way before i posted this question ,it did not work also

Answer (score 2):

In Perforce, you can have a many-to-one mapping but you cannot have a one-to-many mapping. You cannot sync same file to 2 locations. you need to provide it explicit list of what you want to sync. Something like this:

```
//depot/adir/... //cws/build/AA/adir/...
+//depot/adir/exception.c //cws/build/BB/adir/exception.c
```